# “See these guys [infinitive]” vs. “see these guys [present participle]”

Tags: grammaticality, differences, present-participles, bare-infinitive

Which is correct:

> I am excited to see these guys **growing** up.

or

> I am excited to see these guys **grow** up.

Having hard time figuring out how to use gerunds in a sentence.

Comment: I don't think *growing* is a gerund in your example - it's just the continuous tense. In that case, the first applies if you're excited to watch the growing process, and the second if you're referring more to the end result.

Comment: Please also see [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both acceptable, and largely interchangeable. In this case, there's a slight difference of emphasis in that *growing up* shows more interest in the process, and *grow up* more interest in the result. So the former means the pleasure would come from seeing the "guys" as they grew and learnt new things, while the latter refers more to the pleasure of seeing what kind of adults they grow into.